# g++/ld (linking) undefined symbol

Tags: g++, linker-errors

Try to link object file with static and dynamic library to exe.
What goes wrong?
Same result without -ldsound (dsound.lib; in same dir as project files, like new.o)

```
    $ g++ -static d:/lib/libstk.a new.o -ldsound -o new.exe

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) select
>>> referenced by libstk.a(Messager.cpp.obj):(socketHandler)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __WSAFDIsSet
>>> referenced by libstk.a(Messager.cpp.obj):(socketHandler)
>>> referenced by libstk.a(Messager.cpp.obj):(socketHandler)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) WSAGetLastError
>>> referenced by libstk.a(Messager.cpp.obj):(socketHandler)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) CoInitialize
>>> referenced by libstk.a(RtAudio.cpp.obj):(RtAudio::openRtApi(RtAudio::Api))
>>> referenced by libstk.a(RtAudio.cpp.obj):(RtApiDs::RtApiDs())

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) CoUninitialize
>>> referenced by libstk.a(RtAudio.cpp.obj):(RtApiDs::~RtApiDs())

.............and so on ..................
```

I Found a Cmake-file produced after running a configure-script that contains this:

```
# Create imported target stk
add_library(stk STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(stk PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "Threads::Threads;winmm;ole32;wsock32;dsound"
)
```

Maybe I have to use this file (stk-config.cmake) in stead of the commandline g++ with parameters. But no clue how to do this. (No experience with make-files)

Comment: This command is missing Windows libraries, wsock32 ole32 and possibly others.

Comment: Yes. I figured that out. And that is what I found back in that specific make-file. But don't know how to compile the cpp or link the object file using the make-file.